# I would like to copy a range of cells based on a if statement in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to copy a range of cells based on a criteria. I am using the following:

`=IF(B6="Ryde",Sheet2!A4:J15,Sheet2!A18)`

If the criteria is false I get the single cell but when true I get `#value!`. I do not want to use a VB statement or macro if it can be avoided. I have tried naming the range of cells and that makes no difference.

I have asked Mr Google but can only find reference to copying a single cell.

Thanks

Comment: how do you imagine `Sheet2!A4:J15` should be placed in singe cell?

Answer (score 0):

This is only an example.

In Sheet1 hi-light cells **C7** thru **K18**

Then click in the formula bar and enter the array formula:

```
=IF(B6="Ryde",Sheet2!A4:J15,Sheet2!A18)
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

You can pick another block in Sheet1, but it must be the same "shape" as the block in Sheet2!